# What's the most commonly used terminology for a 2d array/list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, standards, terminology

Because in Python list is the built in data type, not array, I see see many questions in python referring to this type of data differently, as a 2d array, a 2d list, a list of lists, a table, and a variety of other expressions. What's the most appropriate standard?

Comment: Seems like there's been a unanimous vote in favor of "a list of lists".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think only "list of lists" makes sense.  Terms like "2d array" and "table" misleadingly imply that tabular structure is tracked or encoded in the data, which it isn't.  That is, if you have `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`, nothing stops you from appending an item to just one of the lists to get `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 88], [5, 6]]`, which is no longer a tabular structure as the "rows" have different lengths.  The outer list does not "know" that what it contains is other lists, so it can't be used in any special way as a "table"; it's just a list, and if you want to use the lists inside it, you have to get them as you would any other list item.

For this reason, I think it's best to avoid terms that suggest that a list of lists is some structure in and of itself, with its own properties apart from those of lists.  It's not.  A list of lists is just a list of lists, and it has no functionality above and beyond that of the lists that make it up.  This is in contrast to true tabular data structures like numpy arrays, which enforce the dimensionality and prevent you from doing things like creating rows of unequal size.

Comment: Well, for now, but with Python 3.5, the `@` operator will make lists more like matrices...

Comment: Or should I say, make the term matrix a better term for specific lists.

Comment: @user667648: The @ operator will not work on lists, see [the PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#non-definitions-for-built-in-types).  It's being added to work with numpy arrays and other such structures.

Comment: Sorry! My bad! Didn't realize that!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I have been writing code professionally for a few years now and have just started working a new job 2 months ago where we use python. I feel like most python people will know what you are talking about if you say "this function accepts a 2D array of data". But as Mr. BrenBarn has stated, I think the 'proper' terminology would be a list of lists. Python lists are more mutable than other typical arrays. In many languages an array refers to a series of similar values like an array of ints or an array of strings. Python lists are not limited to a single heterogeneous data type within the list and therefore I think using the list or list of lists terminology is the way to go if you want to be proper. For me personally I have it engrained in my memory to just call it an array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a rockstar in python, but considering the nature of list, I think it would be more **appropriate** to call list of list. However, it's valid to name this as N-dimensional list.

Just for curiosity, if you search in google:

- python 2d array: *853k results*
- python 2d list: *2,590k results*
- python list of list: *68,300k results*

As you can see, list of list is the most used.